# HTML generation in C#

Tags: c#, html

I have a method that generates some HTML, but it looks ugly to me. Maybe there are some better solutions for this?

```
 public static string GetReview(Quiz quiz)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        string questionSection = string.Format(
            "<div class=\"alert alert-info\" >" +
                "<strong style='color:#000000'>{0}</strong>" +
            "</div>", quiz.Question.GetText());


        string correctAnswer = quiz.Answer.GetText();
        string userAnswer = quiz.UserAnswer?.GetText() ?? string.Empty;

        string answerSection;
        if (correctAnswer == userAnswer) {
            answerSection = string.Format(
                "<p style='margin: 10px 0px 5px 400px;'>" +
                    "Your correct answer:" +
                 "</p>" +
                 "<div class='alert alert-success review-correct'>" +
                    "<strong>{0}</strong>" +
                 "</div>", correctAnswer);
        } else {
            answerSection = string.Format(
                @"<p style='margin: 10px 0px 5px 400px;'>" +
                    "The correct answer was:" +
                 "</p>" +
                 "<div class='alert alert-success review-correct'>" +
                    "<strong>{0}</strong>" +
                 "</div>" +
                 "<br/>" +
                 "You had selected: " +
                 "<span style='color:#a94442'>{1}</span>", correctAnswer, userAnswer);
        }

        string explanationSection = ForQuiz(quiz);

        sb.AppendFormat("<p>{0}</p><p>{1}</p><p>{2}</p>", questionSection, answerSection, explanationSection);

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: C# has a [`HtmlTextWriter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmltextwriter(v=vs.110).aspx) class for this purpose.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41158/discussion-on-question-by-l3xer-html-generating-in-c-code).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before we move to the generation part, let's talk about your html...

```html
<p>
    <!-- questionSection -->
    <div class="alert alert-info" >
        <strong style='color:#000000'>question</strong>
    </div>
</p>
<p>
    <!-- answerSection: correct -->
    <p style='margin: 10px 0px 5px 400px;'>The correct answer was:</p>
    <div class='alert alert-success review-correct'>
        <strong>good answer</strong>
    </div>
    
    <br/>
    You had selected: <span style='color:#a94442'>bad answer</span>

    <!-- answerSection: wrong -->
    <p style='margin: 10px 0px 5px 400px;'>Your correct answer:</p>
    <div class='alert alert-success review-correct'><strong>qwe</strong></div>
</p>
<p>
    <!-- reviewSection -->
    <!-- ForQuiz(quiz) -->
</p>
```

1. `<p>` can only nest phrasing content. `<div>` and `<p>` both belongs to flow content and palpable content. Therefore, you can't nested these 2 under `<p>` element. For the definition of a phrasing content consult this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9852381).
2. *Personally*, I would prefer using `<p>` to separate block of text, instead of using a `<br />` to insert a line-break.

```html
    <!-- Question Section -->
    <div class="alert alert-info" >
        <strong style='color:#000000'>question</strong>
    </div>

    <!-- Answer Section: correct -->
    <p style='margin: 10px 0px 5px 400px;'>The correct answer was:</p>
    <div class='alert alert-success review-correct'>
        <strong>good answer</strong>
    </div>
    
    <p>You had selected: <span style='color:#a94442'>bad answer</span></p>

    <!-- Answer Section: wrong -->
    <p style='margin: 10px 0px 5px 400px;'>Your correct answer:</p>
    <div class='alert alert-success review-correct'>
        <strong>the answer</strong>
    </div>

    <!-- Review Section -->
    <!-- ForQuiz(quiz) -->
```

As for html generation, I believe, it is better to use a templating engine, such as [RazorEngine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9852381) which allows you to  write C# code within the template itself :

**review.cshtml** :

```
@{
    var correctAnswer = Model.Answer.GetText();
    var userAnswer = Model.UserAnswer == null ? Model.UserAnswer.GetText() : string.Empty;
}

<!-- Question Section -->
<div class="alert alert-info">
    <strong style='color:#000000'>@Model.Question.GetText()</strong>
</div>

<!-- Answer Section -->
@if (userAnswer == correctAnswer)
{
    <p style='margin: 10px 0px 5px 400px;'>The correct answer was:</p>
    <div class='alert alert-success review-correct'>
        <strong>@correctAnswer</strong>
    </div>
    <p>You had selected: <span style='color:#a94442'>@userAnswer</span></p>
}
else
{
    <p style='margin: 10px 0px 5px 400px;'>Your correct answer:</p>
    <div class='alert alert-success review-correct'>
        <strong>@correctAnswer</strong>
    </div>
}

<!-- Review Section -->
<!-- TODO: implement ForQuiz(quiz) in razor syntax... -->
```

**generation code** :

```
public string GetReview(Quiz quiz)
{
    var path = Desktop.GetFile("review.cshtml"); // TODO: fix this path
    var template = File.ReadAllText(path);

    return Engine.Razor.RunCompile(template, path, typeof(Quiz), quiz);
}
```

---

EDIT: I noticed you used the null-propagation operator from c# 6. You can also use the new string interpolation to format the html :

```
public static string GetReview3(Quiz quiz)
{
    var builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.Append($@"
        <div class='alert alert-info'>
            <strong style='color:#000000'>{quiz.Question.GetText()}</strong>
        </div>
    ");

    string correctAnswer = quiz.Answer.GetText();
    string userAnswer = quiz.UserAnswer?.GetText() ?? string.Empty;
    if (correctAnswer == userAnswer)
    {
        builder.Append($@"
            <p style='margin: 10px 0px 5px 400px;'>The correct answer was:</p>
            <div class='alert alert-success review-correct'>
                <strong>{correctAnswer}</strong>
            </div>
            <p>You had selected: <span style='color:#a94442'>{userAnswer}</span></p>
        ");
    }
    else
    {
        builder.Append($@"
            <p style='margin: 10px 0px 5px 400px;'>Your correct answer:</p>
            <div class='alert alert-success review-correct'>
                <strong>{correctAnswer}</strong>
            </div>
        ");
    }

    builder.Append(ForQuiz(quiz));


    return builder.ToString();
}
```